# Redirecting URLs with Django to an external site

Tags: django, redirect

I am trying to redirect a number of pages to an external website away from my Django site. Normally I use htaccess for this kind of redirecting but in this case I can not change the configuration on the server and need to do the redirection within Django. Here are some examples:

> http://djangosite.com/products/10 -> http://example.com/products/10
>   http://djangosite.com/products/search ->
>   http://example.com/products/search
>   http://djangosite.com/products/10/edit ->
>   http://example.com/products/10/edit
>   http://djangosite.com/products/10/review ->
>   http://example.com/products/10/review

Can I do this redirection with Django? Here is what I have:

```
path('products/<slug:slug>', RedirectView.as_view(url='http://example.com/products/'+slug, permanent=True)),
```

But it returns `NameError: name 'slug' is not defined`

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use old-style dictionary formatting to insert the kwargs.

```
path('products/<slug:slug>', RedirectView.as_view(url='http://example.com/products/%(slug)s', permanent=True)),
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new redirect view and override the **`get_redirect_url()`** method as,

```
class CustomRedirectView(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return "http://example.com/products/{}".format(kwargs['slug'])
```

and in your urls, use the newly created view

```
path('products/<slug:slug>', CustomRedirectView.as_view(permanent=True)),
```